# iPad Camera Photo to Website -- Can this be done?

Tags: objective-c, ipad

Helping out a friend here, and thought I would play with programming an iPad. Here is the requirement.

The user (HR) wants to use an iPad (iOS6) to take a picture, and the picture is seemlessly uploaded to the corp web page, the user is on.  They totally want to skip the part where you normally browse and upload a photo.

They just want to take a picture, and have the picture show up on the web page. What is the most seemless way to do this? Providing the best user experiance?

My thoughts are to write an app to access the camera, and then upload the image via webservices to the website. But, since this is my first adventure into programming in the iPad world, I thought I would check with the more experianced here.

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: The most seamless way is most certainly writting an app, what exactly is your question?

Comment: Mainly my confirmation that this is the correct way to do this. I've never written an app for an iPad, so I don't want to go down a dead end road.  I don't want to make sure I'm missing something obvious.  So, my next question is, are there any examples out there, of how to do this? I'm sure I'm not the 1st to want this. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Well the main hurdel is going to be the deployment of your app, are you going to deploy it via the app store or just to a couple devices via Apple Developer Center. Just so you know to actually deploy apps you will have to pay at least 99$ per year.

Comment: This would be a private app, and only used internally in the company. So, are you saying, a developer (me) would still need to pay Apple $99/yr, just to deploy your own app on the ipad?? Really appreciate you taking your time out to point me in the right direction.

Comment: yes - in fact you can only develop on the emulator for free. As soon as you want to deploy to a real device you will have to have the 99 $ subscription

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would definitely be a perfect first iPad programming project, but be sure to pick up a decent iOS Programming book (like [the one](http://www.bignerdranch.com/book/ios_programming_the_big_nerd_ranch_guide_rd_edition_) by Joe Conway & Aaron Hillegass) to get yourself familiar with the building blocks of a good iOS citizen.

Then you may want to watch [a video](http://objective-c.wonderhowto.com/how-to/upload-image-website-from-apple-ios-application-333979/) about your question and ask questions on StackOverflow to help you on next steps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, doing this with an app is the most seemless way.

Be aware of the actual deployment, you can either deploy it publicly via the app store (provided you pass the rigerous testing by apple) or you could deploy it via Apple Developer Center, this is going to cost you at least 99$ per year, this will only allow you to deploy the app to a maximum of 100 Devices directly.

There is also a corporte programm that allows you to push internal apps directly to the devices think it was about 300 $ per year.

Also you will need a Mac to develop for ios devises.